# what does mean "line box" in css

Tags: html, css

In css docs there is many mentions of *line boxes* (for example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height)). What does it exactly mean?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

CSS 2.1 specification explains the concept in `9.4.2 Inline formatting contexts` section http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-formatting

> The rectangular area that contains the boxes that form a line is called a **line box**.
>
> ...
>
> When several inline-level boxes cannot fit horizontally within a single **line box**, they are distributed among two or more vertically-stacked line boxes. Thus, a paragraph is a vertical stack of line boxes.
>
> ...
>
> When an inline box exceeds the width of a line box, it is split into several boxes and these boxes are distributed across several line boxes. If an inline box cannot be split (e.g., if the inline box contains a single character, or language specific word breaking rules disallow a break within the inline box, or if the inline box is affected by a white-space value of nowrap or pre), then the inline box overflows the line box.

Answer (score 8):

In this fiddle you can also see that the kind of box that contains the line itself is the line-box. It has a border, too.
http://jsfiddle.net/LyVf5/

HTML:

```
<p>
    <span>With HTML/CSS, *everything* is laid out using a box.</span> 
    <br>
    <br>
    <span>This is a &lt;span>.  It has a border around it, so you can see how your browser positions it.  Notice that when the line wraps, the "box" that the line is in wraps also.  Maybe this is what you're asking about?  More text...  This is a &lt;span>.  It has a border around it.  Notice that when the line wraps, the "box" that the line is in wraps also.    More text...</span>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
p{ 
    margin: 2em; 
}
span{ 
    border: 1px dotted gray; 
    line-height: 150%; 
    padding: 3px; 
}
```

Comment: Nice demonstration, but actually it's the *inline boxes* that have the border, not the line box.

Comment: @Alohci why not the *line box*?

Comment: @MaximPro - look at the last line. If the line box had the border, the border would extend to the right edge of the container, rather than being immediately after the last character.

Comment: @Alohci I do not understand you, can you imagine this somehow?

Comment: @Alohci The box with dotted border only extends to the end of "More text..." in the last line. So it is the inline box because inline boxes are only as wide as needed to display their content. In the example, try remove the `padding` property and add `background-color: crimson` to the `<p>` element. You'd see that the crimson box is a bit taller than the `<span>`. That's the line box.

Comment: @bytrangle: If the p element contained just a single line, then yes, the crimson box would depict that line's line box. However, that's only because the containing block is exactly one line box high. In the example, the p element contains a stack of several line boxes and it's not possible to depict each line box in the stack independently.

Comment: @Alohci: Oh, sorry I replied to the wrong person. But thank you for the explanation. I've spent hours reading up W3 and only feel like I've understood 20% of line boxes.